# Postgresql update specific fields based on a value (trigger)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am writing a Trigger in Postgresql to update dynamically the content of specific columns of a **revenues table**  based on inserts on a **consultations table**. [**edit**] Here is how my tables look like

```
SELECT * FROM psy_revenues;
id | owner_id | January | February | March | April | etc | etc
---+----------+---------+----------+-------+-------+-----+----
2  | 1        |0        | 0        | 0     | 0     |     |

SELECT * FROM psy_consultations;
id | first_name | last_name |        date                 | payed | owner_id
---+------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------+---------
3  | Gérard     | Bouchard  |2018-12-05 04:49:26.064397+01| 80    |1
4  | Pasti      | Lami      |2018-12-05 23:23:52.454849+01| 60    |2
```

I am looking for a straightforward solution to SET only the column (month) corresponding the timestamp of the NEW row added on **consultations**. This is fairly easy to get the month name based on timestamps in psql: to_char(2018-12-05 04:42:11.66867+01, 'Month') ==> December

[**the problem**] However, I do not know how to use this to indicate which column psql should update. Here is a general idea of what I am looking for. The main problem is that I am using a **value** to denote a **field** (see the SET line). Is there a workaround so I could directly select the relevant field? (I tried several things but I was not very successful)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_revenues()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE psy_revenues
    SET to_char(NEW.date, 'Month') = (
        SELECT SUM(payed) 
        FROM psy_consultations
        WHERE (
            owner_id = NEW.owner_id 
            AND to_char(date, 'Month')=to_char(NEW.date, 'Month')
        )
    );

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_revenues
AFTER INSERT 
ON psy_consultations
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_revenues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dynamic SQL. Please avoid concatenation to avoid SQL injection, use `format`  function and positional arguments

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_revenues()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE 
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format (
            'UPDATE psy_revenues 
              SET  %I = (
                SELECT SUM(payed) FROM psy_consultations WHERE 
                    owner_id =  $1 AND to_char(date, ''MM-YYYY'') = $2 
                    )'
             ,to_char(NEW.date, 'FMMonth') )      --column name to update(%I)
 USING NEW.owner_id , to_char(NEW.date, 'MM-YYYY');--values for owner_id & month
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**EDIT**: It seems `TO_CHAR()` pads spaces for month string, I have added FM modifier ( as suggested by @horse )  to remove it.

See this:

```
knayak=# select '|'||to_char(current_date,'Month')||'|' as mon ;
     mon
-------------
 |December |
(1 row)
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5e44c28ab2d22e488c89aef12dfa7dab)

Comment: ERROR:  the « December  » does not exist for « psy_revenues »
LINE 2:               SET  "December " = (

Comment: Looks like December still count as a str rather than a field name

Comment: @DavidZarebski : That's not the problem.I changed it to 'month' instead of 'Month', check now? I hope your month columns are not created with a different case (using quotes)?

Comment: same issue. My column names are January, February, etc etc. Not sure how my columns are created since they are generated by django models (which might be one of the reasons why I struggled that much). Apart from a SELECT * FROM  psy_revenues; , how can I be sure of the way my column names were generated?

Comment: @DavidZarebski : Edit your question and show us your table definition of both the tables involved and some sample data for each.  It's hard to tell without testing it myself.

Comment: done. This is so weird. The names match but it is as if, no matter want I try, I could not use strings to denote fields names (I am saying it in a very beotian sense)

Comment: @DavidZarebski : Check now. I have modified your trigger code and added an example to show what was wrong. It's  now working as expected, check the demo link.

Comment: No need for trim(). Use the `FM` modifier to get rid of the spaces: `to_char(current_date,'FMMonth')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic sql from within your trigger function : generate a string containing the proper SQL code, and use the `EXECUTE` keyword to run it.

The following code should do the trick :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_revenues()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE 
        new_month text;
        new_owner_id integer;
    BEGIN
        new_month    := to_char(NEW.date, 'Month');
        new_owner_id := NEW.owner_id;
        EXECUTE 
            'UPDATE psy_revenues 
            SET ' || new_month || ' = (
                SELECT SUM(payed) FROM psy_consultations 
                WHERE (
                    owner_id = ' || new_owner_id || ' 
                    AND to_char(date, ''Month'') = ' || new_month || '
                )
            )';

    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```